# How to customize CalendarDatePicker- Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

How to change the top of the calendar and the colors in it?
I'm using **CalendarDatePicker** to do it, but there is no option unfortunately.
Any help will be really usefull.

```
DateTime setDate = DateTime.now();

Widget openDatePicker() {
return Center(
    child: Container(
        // margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50.0, horizontal: 60),
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.orangeAccent, width: 2),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40)),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                spreadRadius: 5,
                blurRadius: 7,
                offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
              ),
            ]),
        child: CalendarDatePicker(
          initialDate: setDate,
          firstDate: DateTime.now(),
          lastDate: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 100000)),
          onDateChanged: (DateTime value) {},
        )));
   }
```

I want that it will look in this way:

[image]

But for now my result looks in this way:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't change UI of the Date Picker using that package you have to build custom widget or try other package like https://pub.dev/packages/calendar_date_picker2